# Vertical crack in foundation

Tags: basement, waterproofing, sealing, basement-refinishing, water-damage

I live in a condo and I have a vertical crack in my foundation in my basement. A company came out twice to prime flex seal the crack which lasted for a year. unfortunately with recent rain it appears that the crack is letting in water again at a higher point in the wall than it was originally letting in water. The condo management company contracted out this foundation company who said that they planned to put a cover over the crack to divert the water coming through the foundation into a drain which will lead to my sump pump system. I was wondering is this the best solution to this problem? I figure that over time with water getting in through the crack, it is only a matter of time before the water continues to freeze and thaw in this cold climate and thereby make the crack worse and redirecting the water coming in my basement is putting a band aid on the problem.

What would be the best solution for this problem? I'm interested in knowing so i could make a suggestion to my condo management company so this doesn't get worse over time.

Answer (score 1):

Once there is a crack with high water it is just about impossible to stop the leak unless a complete perimeter drain is installed. Since you already have a sump directing the water to it is the normal procedure , sometimes a internal drain drain is added this is less expensive than a perimeter drain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it take quite a while for the crack to get worse? Right now I get about half a gallon of water on my basement floor during a heavy rain depending on how long it rains. Would it get worse over the course of years? Or decades

Comment: It may get worse it would be rare for there to be no change a newer building I would expect it to get worse (the crack) but the amount of water may not really change much. It depends on the conditions like if it is a ground water issue or a surface water issue. Surface water is much easier to control moving the water away from the foundation walls by 3-4’ in some cases is all it takes.